# Prevent Phone From Ringing

Tags: android

I saw that there is a way to receive notification on incoming calls. Is there a way to prevent the phone ringing upon incoming call without hanging it up?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the volume to 0, wait for the call to disconnect, then restore the volume. Timing may still lead to a brief ring, but it's the best you can do.